# Sum of series: Is this technicality or just wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we want to prove $\sum a_n b_n$ converges(in this problem $\sum a_n = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n$) given that $\sum a_n^2$ and $\sum b_n^2$ are convergent and $a_n, b_n \geq0 $. Now, I have one correct way to prove this by using the comparison test with $a_n b_n \leq \frac{a_n^2+b_n^2}{2}.$

Okay, so my question is, is it wrong if I write $\sum (a_n - b_n)^2 = \sum{a_n^2} + \sum b_n^2 - 2 \sum{a_n b_n}\geq 0$ in some stages of the proof? Since I do not have the information on whether $\sum(a_n - b_n)^2$ converges or not, is it wrong to say the sum of the series is the sum of two convergent series and one series with unknown convergence? I think yes, because that assumes the convergence of all series on the right hand side.

Comment: Yes, you are right that it's wrong if those are infinite sums. You can use that assertion for finite sums to prove it for infinite sums.

Comment: Yes, they are infinite sums. Sorry I did not specify that. I shall make an edit right now.

Comment: Then my comment is essentially an answer. @kathy4k has posted that as an answer.

Comment: Since you know that $a_n^2+b_n^2 \ge a_nb_n$ and all terms are non negative, you can now sum with abandon.

Comment: Since being pedantic is order of the day, technically in the context of your assumptions what you wrote is correct, however it is not if used as a step in a proof.

Comment: Thank you, everyone.